# strongly typed C++0x enumeration comparison

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, enum-class

why aren't instances of strongly typed C++0x enumerations comparable to each other?

---

Update:  They are comparable in gcc 4.6;  I'm not sure if it worked in gcc 4.4.

Comment: because it is strongly typed :)

Comment: Real question is "what does strongly typed mean?", I think.

Comment: @phresnel: [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing); [strongly-typed enumerations in C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations)

Comment: Also, to defend my question, it would not have been crazy to default-define a comparison operator since an enumeration is based on an integer type, which is comparable.  A user-defined behaviour, or no comparison, would still be possible, although I think this would be a rare case.

Comment: @NeilG: But the whole point of strongly typed enumerations is to prevent accidental misuse. Using the typesystem to your advantage is the exact opposite of a rare case in the advanced C++ cycles, and if you want to enable the really rare case of needing to compare apples with oranges, you can do so by writing your own comparison operator. Or are you asking for why there is not a kind of weakly typed enumerations?

Comment: @phresnel: It's not so rare to ask that objects of a type be sortable by default when there's an obvious way to sort them.  Similarly, they should have also defined std::hash<...> for user-defined types when there's an obvious way to do it.  I think that all languages should automatically-generate more code rather than less, and give the programmer the ability to delete what's undesired.  C++ already does that with copy, default, and rvalue constructors, for example.

Comment: It looks like they are comparable in g++. Is'nt it allowed by the standared? http://ideone.com/zJFZB

Comment: @balki: When I tried it in g++ two years ago, it didn't compile.  Are you defining them as strongly typed?

Comment: Yes. `enum class Gender`. Check my example.

Comment: @balki: Looking back, I'm not sure it was possible in gcc 4.4 to compare strongly typed enumerations of the same type, but maybe I'm wrong.  You're right that that works now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use strongly typed enumerations, it's like making your enum a realy type, a class. Then it follows the same rules as for classes.

Instances of different classes can't be compared to each other by default. You have to define a comparison function (or member function) to make them comparable.

Therefore making an enumeration strongly typed makes it follows this very same rule.

Comment: I don't see any use for an enum without being able to compare with another. IMO, Comparing enum instances of *same* type is *not* a misuse.

Comment: @balki I don't understand your comment. enum class don't forbid comparison of enum with the same type, it forbid comparison with other types. I'll add a precision, in case it was not clear.

Comment: yes. but the question was about enums of same type. However both question and answer is clear now.